# Can't get content value from View Class

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to get the content from template to the View Class.

```
{{view App.IssueView contentBinding='controller.content'}}
```

The model.name is showing fine in the template, but when I try to access the content.name in the view class. it shows undefined.

```
define(['app'], function(App){

App.IssueView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    templateName: "magazines/show/issues",
    didInsertElement: function() {

        var controller = this.get('controller'); // showing Class

        console.log(controller.content); // Showing the Model
        console.log(controller.content.name); // undefinded

    }

});

return App.IssueView;

});
```

Please, help me. Thanks.

Comment: Try `{{view App.IssueView}}` (no content binding). And: `this.get('controller.model.name')`

Comment: I tried. but same undefined shows.

Comment: this works ? controller.get('content.name') or it could be possible that the name is not loaded yet

Answer (score 0):

Because, the model didn't load that time. this is an synchronize promise and it has to be solved by Ember.Deffered.